# Using Mean-Value Theorem for Derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve [Mean Value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) but i ran into a road block trying to solve the question. So the question is:
Assuming

$$ \frac{f(b) − f(a)}{b − a} = f'(c) \quad \text{for some } c \in (a, b)$$

Let $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and $[a, b] = [0, 4]$. Find the point(s) $c$ specified by the theorem.

so i attempted to solve this by first getting the derivative of f which gave me $\frac {1}{2\sqrt{x}}$.  After plugging in into the equation $\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4}} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{0}}}{4- 0}$ gives me $\frac{1}{0}$ which equates to infinity.
Now i am convinced that my answer is incorrect because the theorem states **f(x) is continuous function on the (closed and finite) interval**.

Can someone guide me in the right direction with this equation.

Comment: You tried to calculate  $(f'(a)-f'(b)) /(a-b )$ instead of  $ (f(a)-f(b))/(a-b).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f'(x) = \dfrac 1 {2\sqrt x}$, you need
$$
\frac{\sqrt 4 - \sqrt 0}{4-0} = \frac{f(4) - f(0)}{4-0} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt c}.
$$
If $\dfrac{\sqrt 4} 4 = \dfrac 1 {2\sqrt c}$ then what number is $c$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac1{2\sqrt c}=\frac{\sqrt 4-\sqrt 0}{4-0}=\frac24=\frac12.
$$
Then
$
\sqrt c=1
$, so $c=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct; however, I would like to point out that in lieu of utilizing $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},$$ you utilized $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$.
Before using `MVT`, make sure f is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, which they are here.